# count unique pandas dataframe with condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count

I have a dataframe:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'sku': ['A0', 'A0', 'A2', 'A2', 'A2','A3', 'A3'],
                    'ID': ['10', 'T1', 'T1', 'T2', 'T2','10', '20']})
```

I want to count unique values of IDs, but only when starts with "T". The desired results are:

```
sku
A0    1
A2    2
A3    0
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group by the `sku` and then apply the `str.startswith` function on each group's unique `ID` series to count those the unique IDs that start with "T":

```
>>> df1.groupby('sku').apply(lambda g: pd.Series(g['ID'].unique()).str.startswith("T").sum())
sku
A0    1
A2    2
A3    0
```

Comment: Thank you, but I want to count uniqye values of IDs starting with T.

Comment: I've amended my answer. I missed that in your question initially.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

Vectorised, you can use `pd.Series.value_counts` after filtering your dataframe.

You can use categorical data to ensure all keys are included:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'sku': ['A0', 'A0', 'A2', 'A2', 'A3', 'A3'],
                    'ID': ['10', 'T1', 'T1', 'T2', '10', '20']})

df1['sku'] = df1['sku'].astype('category')
res = df1.loc[df1['ID'].str[0] == 'T', 'sku'].value_counts(sort=False)

print(res)

A0    1
A2    2
A3    0
Name: sku, dtype: int64
```

For unique values, you can use `groupby` + `nunique`:

```
res = df1[df1['ID'].str[0] == 'T'].groupby('sku')['ID'].nunique()
```

Comment: @P.J, See update. You can use `groupby` + `nunique`.`apply` + `lambda` will be inefficient (non-vectorised) here.